# recursion trees and big theta bounds

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Draw recursion trees and use them to find big theta bounds on the solutions to the following recurrences. For each, assume that T(1) = 1 and that n is a power of the appropriate integer.
ex) T(n) = 8T(n-2) + n

There are multiple equations that I have to do with the above directions.  I am lost on finding big theta bounds.  I would prefer examples since I learn easiest that way.  Thank you for any help!